# Keep Task iteration synchronsied with User Story iteration

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

When I move a user story from one iteration to another in TFS 2010, I then have to update the iteration in each child task manually. Otherwise it retains the previous iteration value and the various reports and filters don't produce the intended result.

Can anyone recommend a method, or extension, that will either keep the task iterations synchronised to their user story iterations automatically, or failing that, do it for all user stories/tasks in a product on demand?

Comment: Please see "[Stack Overflow is not in need of your SEO skills](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208)".

Comment: Point taken - thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [**TFS Aggregator**](https://github.com/tfsaggregator/tfsaggregator)

### Example Uses

- Update the state of a Bug, PBI (or any parent) to "In Progress" when a child gets moved to "In Progress"
- Update the state of a Bug, PBI (or any parent) to "Done" when all children get moved to "Done" or "Removed"
- Update the "Work Remaining" on a Bug, PBI, etc with the sum of all the Task's "Work Remaining".
- Update the "Work Remaining" on a Sprint with the sum of all the "Work Remaining" of its grandchildren (i.e. tasks of the PBIs and Bugs in the Sprint).
- Sum up totals on a single work item (ie Dev Estimate + Test Estimate = Total Estimate)

Comment: While v1 couldn't yet do what I wanted when I asked the question, there is now a v2 that appears to have the capability.

Answer (score 1):

You can export all the work items in Excel and mass edit them into the new value.
In order to do so, you need to maintain a work item query and have all WIs within one Team Project. Typically this is an activity that goes down during planning poker when a new iteration is about to start.
I found [this](http://www.slideshare.net/aaronbjork/scrum-with-tfs-2010) presentation by A.Bjork very useful on how to do (among other things) tasks like that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This helps, but doesn't really solve the problem because I still need to (a) remember to do it and (b) make separate edits for each user story that I have moved.